# Synchronize an asynchronous API function for use in a Builder (Chain Commands)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback

I have a Problem with Synchronous execution of Asynchronous code.

This is the API's function, which will pass the loaded element as parameter in to the callback.

```
function loadElement(url, onLoadedCallback)
```

I have a Builder class which should receive the element and then change its properties after it has been loaded.

```
class Builder {
    constructor() {
        this.element = {};
    }

    load(url) {
        loadElement(url, (element) => {this.element = element});
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        return this.element;
    }
}
```

But when I use the Builder like this the returned element stays a empty object.

```
var element1 = new Builder().load('testUrl').build();
console.log(element1);
```

The result is `{}` which I kind of expected, because the element needs about 3 seconds to load and the `console.log(element1)` runs instantly...

What I need is a way to resynchronize the asynchronous callback to ensure that my builder chain gets executed one after each other and `this.element` is not equal to an empty object when I call `.build()` on the Builder.

My main problem is that I can't change the API's load function to return a Promise which would be the nicest solution.

I hope someone can help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make an asynchronous task become synchronous. While you cannot change the `load()` method to return a promise, you can make the builder wrap a promise for the element and have `build()` return a promise:

```
class Builder {
    constructor() {
        this.elementPromise = Promise.resolve({});
    }

    load(url) {
        this.elementPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
            loadElement(url, resolve);
        });
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        return this.elementPromise;
    }
}
```

The usage would be

```
const element1 = await new Builder().load('testUrl').build();
//               ^^^^^
console.log(element1);
```

or

```
new Builder().load('testUrl').build().then(console.log);
```

Comment: thank you for helping me! I thought about Promises but I never had the Idea to use it as a wrapper for the builder

Answer (score -1):

```
class Builder {
constructor() {
    this.element = {};
}

load(url) {
    loadElement(url, (element) => {this.element = element;return this;});
    
}

build() {
    return this.element;
}
```

}

Move return statement into the callback function of loadElement

Comment: this will cause an error: cannot read property build of undefined...
this happens because the load function does not return anything, so it returns undefined by default.